# How to pass pointers correctly

Tags: c++, new-operator

***EDIT***: I changed the title because it suited not nearly the problem, as the `new` operator was not the problem. The formerly title was "Can operator new fail?"

In the code below, before a client connects to the server I create a new Socket object pointer. When a client connects I create the object with `new`. But somehow when I step through the code with the debugger (Eclipse CDT, g++ Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) I see that after the call of the `new` operator the pointer ist still NULL.

```
class Socket
{
public:
    Socket( int domain, int type, int protocol = 0 );
    ~Socket();
    [...]
    int accept( Socket * socket );
    [...]
private:
    Socket();
    int mSocketDescriptor;
    int mNetworkProtocol;
    int mTransportProtocol;
};

[...]

int Socket::accept( Socket * socket )
{
    // Accept one connection (blocking)
    struct sockaddr_in cli_addr;
    socklen_t clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    int ret = ::accept(mSocketDescriptor, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
    if ( ret >= 0 ){
        socket = new Socket();  // <- Here's the problem, socket remains NULL
        socket->mSocketDescriptor  = ret;
        socket->mNetworkProtocol   = this->mNetworkProtocol;
        socket->mTransportProtocol = this->mTransportProtocol;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Mainloop:

```
// Accept all incoming connections in a loop
while(true){

    // Accept one connection (blocking)
    net::Socket * newConn = NULL;
    if (socket.accept(newConn) < 0){
        perror("accept()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}

    // Create a new thread that is talking to the client
    pthread_t nThreadID;
    pthread_create(&nThreadID, NULL, ClientMainThreadProc, newConn);
}
```

I read through the C++ reference. It tells me that a bad_alloc exception should araise if the `new` fails. But that is not the fact so I have no idea whats going wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using an old compiler or compiling without exceptions?

Comment: Try using nothrow new and check if it returns a `NULL`.

Comment: I _think_ you mean `newConn` is still `NULL` in the caller? If so, pass the pointer by reference as a copy of the pointer is being passed to `accept()` so any change is local to the `accept()` function.

Comment: At Pubby: No, at least I did not set it. At tenfour: The word you now know in german :D. At hmjd: Okay, but if my debugger is not kidding me, the pointer does not even change locally.

Comment: The debugger lies sometimes, especially if you compiled with optimizations.

Comment: Thats in case the fact! I now passed the pointer as reference and behold, the pointer changes.Locally as well as in the caller. Damn debugger.

Comment: Yeah - as @hmjd says, you are not returning the Socket class pointer to the caller, just dumping it.  You can either use an extra asterisk to return the class pointer or modify your code to return the pointer instead of 'ret'.  You can inspect the value of 'ret' in the returned class to detect an error, or provide the Socket class with an error check function member.

Comment: @DevNoob 'Damn debugger' - turn optimization off.

Comment: BTW, I found this an interesting read regarding `new` and `nothrow`: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill16.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay the solution to the problem is, as hmjd stated:

> I think you mean newConn is still NULL in the caller? If so, pass the pointer by reference as a copy of the pointer is being passed to accept() so any change is local to the accept() function.

Unfortunately my debugger steered me in the wrong direction, showing the socket pointer note even change locally. But when pass the pointer by reference everthing works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an old compiler (from the previous millenium) or compile in a mode with exceptions disabled the result of `new`ing an object may be null. With a contemporary compiler an exception is thrown if memory allocation fails.

Judging from your code, are you sure that `new` returns null? ... because you assign the pointer to a variable passed by value rather than by reference, i.e., the change is only visible within the function.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **yes**. The [C++ new operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kftdy56f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) can fail and throw an `std::bad_alloc` exception when it does fail. This should happen on any modern compiler with exceptions enabled.

*However* if you are on a rather old compiler, or you have disabled exceptions, the `new` operator **can** silently fail.

Also, just noticed this - you shouldn't use `socket = new Socket();` to use a blank constructor. Use `socket = new Socket;` instead. Note the missing parentheses!

Another thing to worry about (not really sure in your case, just throwing it out there, just in case) is [heap corruption](http://www.efnetcpp.org/wiki/Heap_Corruption). It can really mess things up in weird, unexpected ways and it initially takes forever to track down.

Comment: Does `socket = new Socket;` call the ctor? How does it know which one to chose? Or is this rule of thumb just for ctors with no params valid?

Comment: When you do that, you just call the parameter-less ctor, it it's available.